# Why can't I buffer polygons in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: buffer, merge, arcgis-pro, polygon-creation, warning-000117

I've created a polygon by merging several polygons from the same layer using the merge option under Edit menu. Now I cannot buffer the resulting polygon. I tried repair geometry it didn't help. I'm getting an error message saying `WARNING 000117: Warning empty output generated.` How can I solve this? The distance unit I used is meters. I'm using buffer tool. I set side type to "exclude polygon itself", method: planar and no dissolve.

EDIT: I can't buffer unmerged normal polygons either.

CRS EDIT: CRS of the current map: WGS 1984 Aux...
          CRS of the layer to be buffered: WGS 1984 Aux... (set when creating 
                                                            the feature class)
          CRS for the output set in the environments tab: WGS 1984 Aux...

NOTE: I'm using ArcGIS Pro 2.2.3.

Comment: Have you tried buffering a different layer? Have you tried buffering a layer in a different CRS?

Comment: Welcome! What's the coordinate system of the data, which buffer type are you picking, and what unit for the buffer? Please edit that information into your question.

Comment: Edits done as you requested =) they all seem to match. By the way, the distance unit I used is meters. I'm using buffer tool. I set side type to "exclude polygon itself", method: planar and no dissolve.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that it was the environment that I should have set. I set the environment to a layer that contains the layer to be buffered and it worked. So make sure that the environment is set big enough to comprise the layer itself and the buffer.